# Magento 2.4 Custom Sort Order to Print Multiple PDF Invoices (Grouped Print sorted by Customer Name, then by order date)?

Tags: sort, print, invoice-pdf, multiple

Is it possible to select a range of invoices, apply a sort (say by Customer Name), then to print the selected range in that order?  We have customers placing numerous orders in a week that we list view manually on screen to bring them together.  We need to then print all invoices due to despatch that day in that order (grouped / sorted) by Customer.  This ensures they are consolidated for despatch and and none are missed.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to sort or filter the invoices in admin via any of the columns or filters available. Select some or all of the invoices and then export them as a single **pdf** file.

You can then print out this pdf file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Great answer thank you, but is there a way that the exported pdf file has the invoices in it in the sort or filtered order you selected in the admin panel?  We need to group customer invoices together so we can pick them all at the same time.